# Using knockout to build a dynamic attr

Tags: javascript, attributes, knockout.js

I need to have knockout create the image src for me, but I only have one part of the image location. I am using an items ID as the image names. 
**Works**

```
<img alt="" data-bind="attr: {src: $data.img}">
```

**Needed**

```
  <img alt="" data-bind="attr: {src: /img/clients/$data.img.jpg}">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps try this:

```
<img alt="" data-bind="attr: {src: '/img/clients/' + $data.img + '.jpg'}">
```

Comment: indeed, thanks. Not sure why, but i hadn't thought you could do this :) you missed a bit but the idea was correct `<img alt="" data-bind="attr: {src: '/img/clients/' + $data.img+'.jpg'}">`